# How do I aggregate file content correctly with Apache Camel?

Tags: java, io, apache-camel

I am writing a tool to parse some very big files, and I am implementing it using Camel. I have used Camel for other things before and it has served me well.

I am doing an initial Proof of Concept on processing files in `streaming` mode, because if I try to run a file that is too big without it, I get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`.

Here is my route configuration:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("file:" + from)
            .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
            .bean(new LineProcessor())
            .aggregate(header(Exchange.FILE_NAME_ONLY), new SimpleStringAggregator())
            .completionTimeout(150000)
            .to("file://" + to)
            .end();
}
```

`from` points to the directory where my test file is.

`to` points to the directory where I want the file to go after processing.

With that approach I could parse files that had up to hundreds of thousands of lines, so it's good enough for what I need. But I'm not sure the file is being aggregated correctly.

If i run `cat /path_to_input/file` I get this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5
```

Now on the output directory `cat /path_to_output/file` I get this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
Line 4
Line 5%
```

I think this might be a pretty simple thing, although I don't know how to solve this. both files have slightly different byte sizes as well.

Here is my `LineProcessor` class:

```
public class LineProcessor implements Processor {

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String line = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        System.out.println(line);
    }

}
```

And my `SimpleStringAggregator` class:

```
public class SimpleStringAggregator implements AggregationStrategy {

    @Override
    public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {

        if(oldExchange == null) {
            return newExchange;
        }

        String oldBody = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String newBody = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
        String body = oldBody + "\n" + newBody;

        oldExchange.getIn().setBody(body);

        return oldExchange;
    }

}
```

Maybe I shouldn't even worry about this, but I would just like to have it working perfectly since this is just a POC before I get to the real implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your input files last character is a line break. You split up the file with `\n` and add it back in the aggregator except for the last line. Because there is no new line left the line terminator `\n` is removed from the last line. One solution might by adding the `\n` in advance:

```
String body = oldBody + "\n" + newBody + "\n";
```

Comment: My solution was a bit different but it was 100% based on your idea. Worked well for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The answer from 0X00me is probably correct however you are doing unneeded work probably.

I assume you are using a version of camel higher than 2.3. In which case you can drop the aggregation implementation completely as [according to the camel documentation](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html):

**Camel 2.3 and newer:**

The Splitter will by default return the original input message.

Change your route to something like this(I cant test it):

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
from("file:" + from)
        .split(body().tokenize("\n")).streaming()
        .bean(new LineProcessor())
        .completionTimeout(150000)
        .to("file://" + to)
        .end();
}
```

If you need to do custom aggregation then you need to implement the aggregator. I process files this way daily and always end with exactly what I started with.

Comment: This actually didn't work for me. I get a compliation error on  `completionTimeout` if I don't have a call to `aggregate`, and if I remove that too, nothing gets aggregated. I am using Camel version 2.16.1